# How to parse datetime with Z letter with number after semicolon

Tags: python, datetime

I'm parsing timestamp of event in a log record – `2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z`.
It looks strange to me and I don't know how correct is it. I don'think that `358874554` describe.
I'm trying to parse this example from Python 3.7 like this:

```
dt.datetime.strptime('2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

It generates an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

How to parse such a datetime correctly?
Is this datetime example in log is correct (in terms of ISO or anything)?

Comment: Right, use `fromisoformat`. `Z` is not a fix letter, you should be able to read any time offset.

Comment: Don't run. I do `dt.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z'.replace('Z', '+00:00'))`. I get error `Invalid isoformat string: '2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554+00:00'`

It's seem to be RFC1123 date and time string.

Comment: Note that `pandas.to_datetime` will parse to datetime **including the nanoseconds**; e.g. `pd.to_datetime('2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z')` gives `Timestamp('2020-08-09 03:37:33.358874554+0000', tz='UTC')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dateutil.parser
Like this:

```
>>>>import dateutil.parser as p
>>>>p.parse('2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 9, 3, 37, 33, 358874, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dateutil` module as an alternative:

```sh
$ pip install python-dateutil
```

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.isoparse('2020-08-09T03:37:33.358874554Z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 9, 3, 37, 33, 358874, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: Error: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'parser'